# Class Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase could not be found

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

When I run phpunit to test my controller there always comes the message: `Class Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Controller_TestCase could not be found ...`

All require_once are executed and run without errors.

My files:

**Test.php:**

```
<?php

require_once 'bootstrap.php';

class indexTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    protected function setUp ()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap ()
    {
        $this->frontController->registerPlugin(new DemoApp_Controller_Plugin_Initialize('test', PROJECT_ROOT));
    }

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/');
        $this->assertController('login');
    }   
}
```

**bootstrap.php:**

```
<?php
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/application/'));

set_include_path( APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
        get_include_path() );

require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';     
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php';    
require_once 'PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once APPLICATION_PATH . "/../library/Zend/Loader.php";
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

// Set up the config in the registry path relative to public/index.php
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/config.ini'); //, 'test'
Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);

/*// Set up the database in the Registry
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db);
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
*/

// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
```

Answer (score 1):

The class is not in your include path, Or, you don't have the class at all.
Steps to take:

1. Find the class file
2. Make sure the class is in your
   include path, including the
   auto_loader name parsing:
   Z_Y_YourClass will be looked at the
   include_path/Z/Y/YourClass.php

Good Luck

Comment: The class is defined at the file: "ControllerTestCase.php"
in 'APPLICATION_PATH . "/../library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/'
which is added to the include path in bootstrap.php

Comment: Try for the experiment to use absolute paths and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in your bootstrap to activate the autoloader.

`require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();`

If you create an application object, it does this for you automatically
but otherwise use the above to do it yourself.

Comment: This is actually the solution that worked for me.  The other proposed solutions did not include the Zend_Autoloader which I needed to run the rest of my code.  Note: I think this is only for ZF 1.8+ (I'm using 1.12).

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious first question is, what version of the Zend Framework source do have?  It's in `Zend/Version.php.`

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions which worked for me:

1. create symlink within the tests directory as ln -s ../library/Zend which allows autoloader to find the file
2. add /library to the php include paths - which also helps the autoloader to locate the file

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your bootstrap.php file:

```
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';
```

Worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on the following setup

- downloaded zend 1.12,
- created a project through zf tool: `sh bin/zf.sh create project my-project`
- then run `phpunit` from the root folder of the project.

The **solution** was to `cd tests` and then run phpunit.

The **reason** why this happened is that phpunit needs to bootstrap first.
The bootstrap script is defined in `tests/phpunit.xml` configuration file which will be loaded by default if the file is in the same directory that the command runs.

phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
    ....
```

Alternatively you can call phpunit from any directory specifying the location of  phpunit.xml with the -c argument

```
phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml
```